# Hidden Items Affecting Hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm working to have a CSS-only solution to animating in additional menus/buttons when a first menu/button is hovered.

Hover functionality is triggered in the "invisible" area to the right of the visible button, though (where the sub buttons eventually animate into). I only want the menu to initially trigger/animate in when the main/first button is hovered.

Shown below and in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/breyman/pen/zYJeqqV). I'm using/animating a combination of opacity, x transform, and visibility, but the visibility seems to be triggering when hovering over the invisible items.

I tried moving the animation down into the btn-trigger, but that made it so hovering around/selecting the sub menu became extremely erratic.

```css
.btn-color-selector {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.btn-trigger,
.btn-color {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.btn-color {
  background-color: coral;
}

.btn-color {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
  transition: opacity 300ms ease, transform 300ms ease, visibility 300s linear 300ms;
}

.btn-color-selector {
  margin-right: -40px;
}

.btn-color-selector:hover>.btn-color,
.btn-color:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: opacity 300ms ease, transform 300ms ease, visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-color-selector">
    <div class="btn-trigger"></div>
    <div class="btn-color"></div>
    <div class="btn-color"></div>
    <div class="btn-color"></div>
    <div class="btn-color"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/d7j83goa/13/

Comment: `visibility` is not animatable, you may remove it completely. `opacity` is enough.

Comment: @Kosh - in this case, opacity isn't enough. Visibility is required or else the items are still there and hoverable.

Comment: @ianworsley - that looks to have done it! It appears adding the extra visibility transition properties to be the following was all that was needed. Thank you so much!!
`transition: opacity 300ms ease, transform 300ms ease,
    visibility 0ms linear 0ms;
transition: opacity 300ms ease, transform 300ms ease,
    visibility 300s linear 300ms;`

Answer (score 1):

Use the triggers hover with the general sibling selector on the btn-color class should do the trick.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

```
.btn-trigger:hover ~ .btn-color{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
   **strong text** transition: opacity 300ms ease, transform 300ms ease;
}
```